# Switch from odbc to oledb in crystal reports at runtime

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have report with subreports. Part of them are using OBDC database type.
I want to set all subreports to OLE DB with new connection parameters
I've tried the following but as I understand this isn't enough.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= rd.DataSourceConnections.Count - 1; i++)
{
  rd.DataSourceConnections[i].SetConnection(logonProps["Data Source"].ToString(),
                                                          logonProps["Initial Catalog"].ToString(), 
                                                          true);
 }
 for (int i = 0; i <= rd.Subreports.Count - 1; i++)
 {
   for (int x = 0; x <= rd.Subreports[i].DataSourceConnections.Count - 1; x++)
                {
                    rd.Subreports[i].DataSourceConnections[x].SetConnection(logonProps["Data Source"].ToString(),
                                                                            logonProps["Initial Catalog"].ToString(),
                                                                            true);
                }
            }
```

What property should I set to change database type?

Answer (score 0):

i haven't answer for your question but i think you want create report from known data source.
if its true you can read data into a c# data source like DataTable or List and set it as data source of sub report

`rptMain.Subreport[0].SetDatasource(_dataTable);`